# Sendgrid integration - no mail is being sent

Tags: python, email, sendgrid

I have recently created a SendGrid account and I'd like to integrate SendGrid for Python.

I have tried both types of integration: Web API and SMTP Relay  - none of them seem to work. My message in not being delivered, therefore I can't complete my integration. SendGrid is saying that my email 'was not seen yet'.

[image]

**1. This is the script I used to test WebAPI integration (yes, environment variable is set):**

```
import sendgrid
import os
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import *

sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
from_email = Email("me@gmail.com")
to_email = Email("me@gmail.com")
subject = "Sendgrid test"
content = Content("text/plain", "Just a test")
mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
print(response.status_code)
print(response.body)
print(response.headers)
```

Output:

```
202

Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 09 Jun 2017 23:16:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
X-Message-Id: nyLE-nOUQrSWyw84qQ-xuw
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html
```

**2. This is the script for the SMTP Relay integration test:**

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

msg=MIMEMultipart()
msg['From']='Test'
msg['Subject']='This is a test message.'
msg.attach(MIMEText('Hello World'))

fromaddr = 'me@gmail.com'
toaddrs  = 'me@gmail.com'

username = 'apikey'
password = "SG.[cut].[cut]"

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.sendgrid.net:587')
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Debug output:

```
send: 'ehlo [ip.address]\r\n'
reply: '250-smtp.sendgrid.net\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 31457280\r\n'
reply: '250-STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: '250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN\r\n'
reply: '250 AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: smtp.sendgrid.net
8BITMIME
PIPELINING
SIZE 31457280
STARTTLS
AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: '220 Begin TLS negotiation now\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: Begin TLS negotiation now
send: 'ehlo [ip.address]\r\n'
reply: '250-smtp.sendgrid.net\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 31457280\r\n'
reply: '250-STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: '250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN\r\n'
reply: '250 AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: smtp.sendgrid.net
8BITMIME
PIPELINING
SIZE 31457280
STARTTLS
AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
send: 'AUTH PLAIN AGFwaWtleQBTRy53T2M1YnN2NVJKbXlYczNoMkJYMFV3LmVHc0ZIbkZWUTViM2xfSlM2V0hUd0xwU1JFendsSVZaMnVralI1ZllxTHc=\r\n'
reply: '235 Authentication successful\r\n'
reply: retcode (235); Msg: Authentication successful
send: 'mail FROM:<me@gmail.com> size=293\r\n'
reply: '250 Sender address accepted\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: Sender address accepted
send: 'rcpt TO:<me@gmail.com>\r\n'
reply: '250 Recipient address accepted\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: Recipient address accepted
send: 'data\r\n'
reply: '354 Continue\r\n'
reply: retcode (354); Msg: Continue
data: (354, 'Continue')
send: 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============1872430840=="\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nFrom: Test\r\nSubject: This is a test message.\r\n\r\n--===============1872430840==\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\nHello World\r\n--===============1872430840==--\r\n.\r\n'
{}
reply: '250 Ok: queued as -u6z[...]_Yg\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: Ok: queued as -u6z[...]_Yg
data: (250, 'Ok: queued as -u6z[...]_Yg')
send: 'quit\r\n'
reply: '221 See you later\r\n'
reply: retcode (221); Msg: See you later
```

As I said in both cases, my email message is not being delivered for some reason. Is there something I'm missing in my configuration?

Comment: Everything looks good from what you've posted. Check the SendGrid portal to see what happened to the email after it queued it.

Comment: @Barmar The thing is.. nothing appears in my supressions or activity on SendGrid. In my account overview it also tells that 0 requests have been made.

Comment: Well, that's really strange since it clearly says that it queued the message. The `202` status code from the WebAPI also means that the message was accepted and queued. I suggest you contact SendGrid tech support, give them the ID from the "queued" message, and ask them to trace it.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your solution. I will contact them as you said.